# Creating a Mixin class for pandas DataFrame and native Python dict

Tags: python, pandas, dictionary, get, mixins

**How to create a mixin class for pandas DataFrame and native Python dict such that the dataframe columns can be accessed like a nested dict?**

From [Accessing pandas DataFrame as a nested list](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44104321/accessing-pandas-dataframe-as-a-nested-list), using the `df.loc()` function is the way to access the row/column/slices desired.

But the goal is to access the 2-D dataframe using the same syntax as a native Python dict. E.g.

```
>>> import pandas as pd
>>> df = pd.DataFrame([['x', 1,2,3,4,5], ['y', 6,7,8,9,10], ['z', 11,12,13,14,15]])
>>> df.columns = ['index', 'a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e']
>>> df = df.set_index(['index'])
>>> df
        a   b   c   d   e
index                    
x       1   2   3   4   5
y       6   7   8   9  10
z      11  12  13  14  15

>>> df['x']
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5]

>>> df['x']['a']
1

>>> df['x']['a', 'b']
(1, 2)

>>> df['x']['a', 'd', 'c']
(1, 4, 3)
```

I've tried to create a mixin class as such:

```
from pandas import DataFrame

class VegeTable(DataFrame, dict):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        DataFrame.__init__(self, *args, **kwargs)
    def __getitem__(self, row_key, column_key):
        if type(row_key) != list:
            row_key = [row_key]
        if type(column_key) != list:
            column_key = [column_key]
        return df.loc[row_key, column_key]
```

But I think there's something missing such that the dictionary key access didn't work and the `dict.get` returns a strange values:

```
>>> from pandas import DataFrame
>>> 
>>> 
>>> class VegeTable(DataFrame, dict):
...     def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
...         DataFrame.__init__(self, *args, **kwargs)
...     def __getitem__(self, row_key, column_key):
...         if type(row_key) != list:
...             row_key = [row_key]
...         if type(column_key) != list:
...             column_key = [column_key]
...         return df.loc[row_key, column_key]
... 
>>> 
>>> vt = VegeTable([['x', 1,2,3,4,5], ['y', 6,7,8,9,10], ['z', 11,12,13,14,15]])
>>> vt.columns = ['index', 'a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e']
>>> vt = vt.set_index(['index'])
>>> vt
        a   b   c   d   e
index                    
x       1   2   3   4   5
y       6   7   8   9  10
z      11  12  13  14  15
>>> vt['x']
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pandas/core/frame.py", line 2062, in __getitem__
    return self._getitem_column(key)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pandas/core/frame.py", line 2069, in _getitem_column
    return self._get_item_cache(key)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pandas/core/generic.py", line 1534, in _get_item_cache
    values = self._data.get(item)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pandas/core/internals.py", line 3590, in get
    loc = self.items.get_loc(item)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pandas/core/indexes/base.py", line 2395, in get_loc
    return self._engine.get_loc(self._maybe_cast_indexer(key))
  File "pandas/_libs/index.pyx", line 132, in pandas._libs.index.IndexEngine.get_loc (pandas/_libs/index.c:5239)
  File "pandas/_libs/index.pyx", line 154, in pandas._libs.index.IndexEngine.get_loc (pandas/_libs/index.c:5085)
  File "pandas/_libs/hashtable_class_helper.pxi", line 1207, in pandas._libs.hashtable.PyObjectHashTable.get_item (pandas/_libs/hashtable.c:20405)
  File "pandas/_libs/hashtable_class_helper.pxi", line 1215, in pandas._libs.hashtable.PyObjectHashTable.get_item (pandas/_libs/hashtable.c:20359)
KeyError: 'x'
>>> vt.get(['x'])
>>> vt.get('x')
>>> vt.get('x', 'a')
'a'
>>> vt.get('x', ['a', 'b'])
['a', 'b']
>>> vt.get('x', ['a', 'b'])
```

**How to create a mixin class for pandas DataFrame and native Python dict such that the dataframe columns can be accessed like a nested dict?** Is that possible at all? If so, how?

Comment: If you were to use `__getitem__` for row access, instead of the current column access, how do you propose doing column access?

Comment: The same as how a nested dict `defaultdict(dict)` would be accessed, i.e. `vt[row_ids, column_ids]` And for row(s) access, `vt[row_ids]`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> **Error in reasoning**.
>
> > 1. `vt = vt.set_index(['index'])`
> >        This will redefine `df` to `<class 'pandas.core.frame.DataFrame'>`.
> >        You have to overload it or `Typecast` the resulting `df`.
> > 2. `def __getitem__(self, row_key, column_key=None):`
> >        Only **one** Parameter is passed to `def __getitem__(...`.
> >        Multiple Parameter have to be inside `[...]`,
> >        e.g. vt['x', ['a', 'b', 'c']]

If you accept this slightly different notation,
this implementation do what you want:

```
class DataFrame2(DataFrame):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)

    def __getitem__(self, item):
        if isinstance(item, tuple):
            row = self.loc[item[0]]
            sub_item = item[1]
            if isinstance(sub_item, list):
                r = [row.loc[key] for key in sub_item]
                if len(r) == 1:
                    return r[0]
                else:
                    return tuple(r)
            else:
                # NotImplemented, Parameter other than tuple('x', [list])
                raise Exception(NotImplemented)
        else:
            return tuple(self.loc[item])

    def set_index(self, index):
        return DataFrame2(super().set_index(index))

# Usage:
df = DataFrame2(data)
df.columns = ['index', 'a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e']
df = df.set_index(['index'])

print('df[\'x\']={}\n'.format(df['x']))
print('df[\'x\'][\'a\']={}\n'.format(df['x',['a']]))
print('df[\'x\'][\'a\', \'b\']={}\n'.format(df['x', ['a', 'b']]))
print('df[\'x\'][\'a\', \'b\', \'c\']={}\n'.format(df['x', ['a', 'b', 'c']]))
```

> **Output**:
>
> > ```
> > df['x']=(1, 2, 3, 4, 5)
> > df['x']['a']=1
> > df['x']['a', 'b']=(1, 2)
> > df['x']['a', 'b', 'c']=(1, 2, 3)
> > ```

***Tested with Python: 3.4.2***

Answer (score 0):

I don't think it's good idea to create create a mixin class. When you use pandas you should think in pandas way. And I also doubt that native  Python nested dict can be assess by this way:

```
In []: df['x']['a', 'b']
```

But, if you insist, try this code first:

```
In []: df.T.to_dict()
Out[]:
{'x': {'a': 1, 'b': 2, 'c': 3, 'd': 4, 'e': 5},
 'y': {'a': 6, 'b': 7, 'c': 8, 'd': 9, 'e': 10},
 'z': {'a': 11, 'b': 12, 'c': 13, 'd': 14, 'e': 15}}
```